# Send File using FileStream, Stream, ByteArray

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, stream

I'm writing a file upload function which can be used in both website and web service.

The function took `ByteArray` and wrote to the server using `FileStream`.

> ```
>     Public Shared Function FileUpload(ByRef content As Byte(), ByVal fullPath As String) As Boolean
>         Dim fileStream As FileStream = Nothing
>         Try
>
>             fileStream = New FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
>             fileStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length)
>
>             Return True
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             Return False
>         Finally
>             If Not fileStream Is Nothing Then
>                 fileStream.Dispose()
>             End If
>         End Try
>     End Function
> ```

In the website, I used a FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream and read it into the byteArray (content).

I have another application running on a FTP server sending local files to the same web server.
So it read the file to a FileStream and convert to byteArray and call the `FileUpload` function through a web service.

Is there a better solution for this situation? Can I send a Stream (MemoryStream) or FileStream instead of a ByteArray. Which is more efficient?